# Reinit javascript functions when page change with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to make my one page website multilingual, and I want to dynamically refresh the content on calling a ajax function.

I don't want that the user have to reload the page, so I call a ajax function that will retrieve the new language datas (who are stocked in a .json file).

I don't have problems for that but when the new content is loaded, all the javascripts functions doesn't work anymore.

I tried to encapsulate all of the initialisation functions under a "master function" like pageInit(); but that doesn't work either.

I uploaded the development version of my website for the debugging time :

http://cv.gillequentin.be/
The first loading is correct but try to change the lang on clicking on the "FR" or "EN" button, no more javascript ?

I'm working with jQuery and Laravel 4.

Thanks for the help !

Comment: catched a error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: pageCvInit is not defined`

Comment: Yep, that's the master function for the Initialization of the page, but it didn't work in this way, it was just called on the success method after the ajax call

Comment: this function calling 4 time.

Comment: After each ajax call for the page new content, pageCvInit was called, but this way doesn't seem to work well

Comment: did you checked that why sometime its undefine?

Comment: When you arrive on the page, there's a script reference on the very end of the body where are stocked the "pageCvInit()", after the master container div. The ajax function change the content of thi master container, but the script are still on the page (So I don't know why pageCvInit() is undefined, it is still on the page !

Comment: Everything works for me. Where is the error?

Comment: When you click on the "EN" or "FR" button, you will load a different lang for the website, called with a ajax function, but when the content is reloaded, the javascript doesn't work anymore. I will upload the different part of the code if the problem is not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem, so I'll share my solution (who has been due to a lack of attention) the "master function" who initialize all the plugins was encapsulated on the $(document).ready(), in this way the first load of the page worked well, but stopped working after an ajax call. I just take the master function off the $(document).ready(). And now that works well.